# HttpResponse downloading zip file cuts zip file name

Tags: asp.net, webforms, zip

I am using Webforms and I am providing a possibility to download files. However their names have white spaces and commas. What is the way to ensure that all file name will be there? eg if I have a name like:

1991-02-21 1111, ABCD, restofmyfilename.zip
all I get while dowloading is
1991-02-21

code part:

```
            Response.ContentType = "application/zip";
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + response.FileName);
            Response.BinaryWrite(response.Bytes);
            Response.End();
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try wrapping the file name in quotes? For Example:

```
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=\"" + response.FileName + "\"");
```

Comment: That would likely do the trick. But the way you have worded this, it should be a comment, not an answer. I realize that you cannot yet post comments on other peoples' questions, but you could trivially have made this into an answer by simply adding a one liner where you show how to add the quotes. I suggest you update the answer and do just that...

Comment: Thanks. Example added.

Answer (score 0):

You can slightly modify the FileName to avoid white spaces:

```
  string fileName = response.FileName.Replace(' ','_');
```

then use this as a filename in your code.